# A sequential-parallel MPI algorithm: how to achieve this behavior using MPI?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have the following problem and wonder how to achieve this in MPI-Fortran.

Suppose that I have N0 nodes in my cluster, given an interval (1,N), I divide it into N0 segments denoted by (i1,i2) and suppose the calculation time for each (i1,i2) is some T, done in parallel. Now if I make an additional partition of each sub-interval (i1,i2) into N0 smaller ones, let's called (a1,a2), at a given time, I want to work with each (i1,i2) sequentially but with every (a1,a2) in parallel, would the calculation time for (i1,i2) be T/N0, i.e. significantly reduced with respect to the first partition ? and if it does, how can I achieve this idea in MPI ?

Thank you for your suggestions and help.

To update the post, I have come up with the following schematical lines. I hope it is lisible enough to understand, where

- i : index of the sub-interval (i1,i2)
- rank: this is the rank of the current node
- sub_sub_interval(rank, i): variable containing all the subintervals (a1,a2) of the interval (i1,i2).

.

```
do i = 0, number_machine-1

   call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

   start = MPI_Wtime()

   call compute_my_quantity(A, sub_interval(i),
        sub_sub_interval(rank,i))

   end = MPI_Wtime()

   if (rank /= 0) then 
      call SEND_my_quantity(rank, A)
   else 
      do i_prime = 1, number_machine-1
         call RECEV_my_quantity(i_prime, A_sub(i_prime))
      end do
   end if
end do
```

What I get is that: time measured for each (a1,a2) is still the same as

```
   start = MPI_Wtime()

   call compute_my_quantity(A, sub_interval(rank))

   end = MPI_Wtime()

   if (rank /= 0) then 
      call SEND_my_quantity(rank, A)
   else 
      do i_prime = 1, number_machine-1
         call RECEV_my_quantity(i_prime, A_sub(i_prime))
      end do
   end if
```

Maybe you can tell me what is conceptually wrong in this algorithm such that the time needed for (a1,a2) is the same as for (i1,i2) ?

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I probably don't) your question could be rephrased as: *Will decomposing the problem into many small parcels for distribution to processes be a faster route to a solution than decomposing it into fewer large parcels ?*  To which the off-the-shelf reply would be: *No.  Minimise the amount of communication your program indulges in.*

Comment: Remember that Amdahl's law sets the limit for *any* parallel program. For the specific case when MPI is involved, you need to also factor in the time needed for communication between ranks.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have noticed that too with a different algorithm from that of my above initial post. Anyway, I did gain a factor 10 in time using 12 nodes compared with my sequential code. So it is encouraging. Initially, I did naively assume the opposite of your question. And this leads to the above organization which turns out to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from the question,

You have some tasks (say N) that is divided into N0 segments, with each segment taking some N/N0 tasks.

In strategy 1, you distribute this among N0 (or more) ranks and works in parallel.
In strategy 2, you take, a task out of N tasks and distribute this tasks among MPI ranks. Likewise, each tasks are executed sequentially.

Theoretically, strategy1 will always be faster than strategy 2 because of the underlying overheads imposed by the communication. In strategy 2, there will be lot (N0 times more than strategy 1) of communication. So your application performance will be degraded.

Ideal approach will be using **hybrid programming model** in where you distribute the tasks among nodes using MPI and in each node you use some shared memory paradigm (openMP) to speed up the execution. Basically, it is a combination of your strategy 1 and strategy 2.